# How does Intent-Filter choose which Data?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am not seeing another other questions like this, maybe I am just not reading the Google Documentation correctly. I am fairly new to AndroidManifest.xml and just started learning about intent-filters today. I have a task to use Auth0 authentication system, but it requires multiple endpoints and they have suggested adding the endpoints to the AndroidManifest.xml file as an intent-filter.

Android Manifest.xml

```
        <activity android:name="com.auth0.android.provider.RedirectActivity"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="@string/com_auth0_domain_prod"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.someCompany/callback"
                    android:scheme="https"/>

                <data
                    android:host="@string/com_auth0_domain_stg"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.someCompany/callback"
                    android:scheme="https"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

How do I configure the Intent-Filter to know which Data to use? Or do I need to make another Intent-Filter with a separate Data? I am just really confused here and Google Docs are not helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For Context: Auth0 says to put it in ManifestPlaceHolders in build.gradle but that's only if you have 1 domain/endpoint, we have 2!

Comment: this code should handle both the endpoints properly

Comment: @OmkarT Hm... Intent-filters just know which <Data> to use? How does that work. This code isn't working for me btw.

Comment: its not the intent filter that chooses the data but the data that chooses the intent filter. Basically when an intent is launched, android system will query all packages with all intent filters and 'filter' out the list matching the intent labelling them intent handlers

Comment: one of the intent fillter defined by you will be the one in final list filtered by the system and activity will be called,same goes for the other intent filter

Comment: @OmkarT So do I need to specify in my Activity which Intent Filter to use so it knows which endpoint?

Comment: let me give you an anology, Compare declaring two intent filters with 2 methods in helper class. eg doSomething(int a) and doSomething(String s) , You created the methods and marked them public to be used by someone else now it's on the other guy who utilizes your methods in his code to select which method to choose. Similarly you said that for dataA use this activity and for dataB  use this activity (which is same for dataA in this case) Now when systems wants to open dataA it will see your activity available and launch it with dataA, same goes for dataB